# Stringify typescript object to JSON with custom order

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

How can I serialize a typescript object to JSON string so that all properties are serialised in a specific order (not sorted) ?

The order can be interface/class order or if possible using experimental decorators !

Any idea ?

Example :

```
interface Root {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  description: string;
  childs: Child[];
}

interface Child {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  description: string
}

const root = ...

JSON.stringify(root, null, 2);
```

Result :

```
{
  "id": "1000",
  "name": "root name",
  "description": "root description",
  "childs": [{
    "id": "9000",
    "name": "child name 1",
    "description": "child description 1"
    },{
    "id": "9001",
    "name": "child name 2",
    "description": "child description 2"
    }]
}
```

Comment: u mean sort keys? https://www.npmjs.com/package/sort-object-keys2

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this using experimental decorators, e.g. with the `ReflectionCapabilities` and `Decorators` classes from Angular.

First, declare a property decorator, like this:

```
export class Serialized {
}

export interface SerializedDecorator {
    (obj: Serialized): TypeDecorator;

    new(obj: Serialized): Serialized;
}

export const Serialized: SerializedDecorator =
    makePropDecorator('Serialized', (args) => args, Serialized);
```

Your data model would look something like this:

```
class Root {
  @Serialized({})
  id: string;

  @Serialized({})
  name: string;

  @Serialized({})
  description: string;

  @Serialized({})
  childs: Child[];
}

class Child {
  @Serialized({})
  id: string;

  @Serialized({})
  name: string;

  @Serialized({})
  description: string
}
```

Now, to get property information and put together the string, do something like this:

```
export function stringifyOrdered(obj: any): string {
    if(!obj || !obj.__proto__ || !obj.__proto__.constructor)
        return "";

    let serialized = "{";
    const reflect = new ReflectionCapabilities();

    // this gives you the ordered list of properties:
    for (let propMetadata in reflect.propMetadata(obj.__proto__.constructor)) {
        /* put together the stringified object,
        recursively call the serialize function if the value type is object */

        if(obj[propMetadata] instanceof Array){
            serialized += `"${propMetadata}": [`;
            for(let item of <Array<any>>obj[propMetadata]){
                if(['string', 'number', 'boolean'].includes(typeof item)){
                    serialized += `"${item}", `
                } else if (typeof item == 'object'){
                    serialized += `${stringifyOrdered(item)}, `
                }
            }
            serialized = serialized.substr(0, serialized.length - 2);
            serialized += "], ";
        }else{
            if(["string", "number", "boolean"].includes(typeof obj[propMetadata])){
                serialized += `"${propMetadata}": "${obj[propMetadata]}", `
            } else if (typeof obj[propMetadata] == 'object'){
                serialized += `"${propMetadata}": ${stringifyOrdered(obj[propMetadata])}, `
            }
        }

    }

    serialized = serialized.substr(0, serialized.length - 2);
    return serialized + "}";
}
```

I use `ReflectionCapabilities` and `Decorators` in my own project. You can get it from GitHub: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/core/src/reflection/reflection_capabilities.ts and https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/core/src/util/decorators.ts

**Update**: I have tested above code and it works for me. Feel free to use it wherever you want.

A bit of background information: Property declarations get stripped away when transpiling from TypeScript to JavaScript. One way to preserve this information is to annotate all properties. This is only possible in classes, not in interfaces.